# How to know which application run a python script

Tags: python

Is there a way to know which application I'm running a python script from?

I can run python from multiple sources, like Textmate, Sublime Text 2 or Terminal (I'm on Mac OSX). How can I know, exactly which tool launched the current python app.

I've tried looking into the `os` and `inspect` modules, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: what have you tried? if you do `os.system("Textmate")` then it is obvious what you run...

Comment: He is asking the reverse question... where is the python instance launched from...

Comment: I'm curious why you need to know this, because it shouldn't matter how its launched.

Comment: I'm using an application with some modules embedded and extra functionality that I can't get from other apps. And I want my code to know which app run in order to do things one way or other. I need the code cross-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to do this sort of thing in a fairly cross-platform way:

```
import psutil
import os
my_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
parent = my_process.parent
print "Parent process name: " + parent.name
```

From the `psutil` documentation:

> It currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX and FreeBSD, both 32-bit and 64-bit, with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.3 by using a single code base.

As well as the name you can get the executable path (which might be more useful if you're selecting from a list of options) and also the full command-line with which it was invoked. You can also get the username who ran the process. See the [psutil classes documentation](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes) for details of the parameters and the platforms on which they're available.

As an aside, if at all possible I would structure your code so that you *don't* have to modify your behaviour according to the calling application - it would be much preferable to have the calling application pass in a parameter which modifies the behaviour of the shared code. However, I appreciate that sometimes other concerns take precedence over cleanliness of code, so `psutil` should enable you to do what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to stay specific to unix and then you can get the parent PID of the process with `os.getppid()`. If you wanted to translate it back to a program id, you could can run a subprocess to use the relevant OS-specific PID-to-useful-data tool (odds on - `ps`)